# query to get the main block

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this scenario ( I made it up to be similar to my case ) there is a parking lot with 3 floors , all the people they want to drive the car out the parking are blocked by 1 car , so all the people went to the shop/mall and saying which car is blocking behind him , so for example car 2 is being blocked by car 1 , car 12 is being blocked by car 2 , car 99 is being blocked by car 12 and so on.  so as for this simple example the car 1 is blocking all the cars.

```
car_number , blocking_car, floor
1              2            1
2              12           2
7              15           1
9              20           2
12             7            1
15             2            1
20             12           2
99             12           2

SELECT car_number , blocking_car, floor
   FROM parking_cars
START WITH id = 0
CONNECT BY blocking_car= car_number
```

but its not giving the car 1 floor 1

Comment: Where does `id = 0` come from?

Comment: Is your dataset incomplete? There's no car 12.

Comment: @user9601310 i didnt from where to start , i added the car 12 i forget to add it

Comment: That results in a loop -- 12 blocks 7, 7  blocks 15, 15 blocks 2, 2 blocks 12!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the blocked car using `not exists`:

```
select pc.*
from parking_cars pc
where not exists (select 1
                  from parking_cars pc2
                  where pc2.blocking_car = pc.car_number
                 ) and
      floor = 1;
```

This gets the car on floor 1 that is not blocked by any other car.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1aba3621ce8dfd3bbc81a240db8caef1) is a db<>fiddle.